# How to Terminate a Python program before its child is finished running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminate, os.system

I have a script that is supposed to run 24/7 unless interrupted. This script is script A.
I want script A to call Script B, and have script A exit while B is running. Is this possible?
This is what I thought would work

```
#script_A.py
while(1)
    do some stuff
    do even more stuff
    if true:
        os.system("python script_B.py")
        sys.exit(0)


#script_B.py
time.sleep(some_time)
do something
os.system("python script_A.py")
sys.exit(0)
```

But it seems as if A doesn't actually exit until B has finished executing (which is not what I want to happen).
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Try to use `os.system("python script_B.py &")` to start your B script in the background.

Comment: os.system is synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing sounds a lot like a function call:

```
def doScriptB():
  # do some stuff
  # do some more stuff

def doScriptA():
  while True:
    # do some stuff
    if Your Condition:
      doScriptB()
      return

while True:
  doScriptA()
```

If this is insufficient for you, then you have to detach the process from you python process. This normally involves spawning the process in the background, which is done by appending an ampersand to the command in bash:

```
yes 'This is a background process' &
```

And detaching said process from the current shell, which, in a simple C program is done by forking the process twice. I don't know how to do this in python, but would bet, that there is a module for this.

This way, when the calling python process exits, it won't terminate the spawned child, since it is now independent.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to detach a system call to another thread.

## script_A.py

```
import subprocess
import sys

while(1)
    do some stuff
    do even more stuff
    if true:
        pid = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "python script_B.py"]) # call subprocess
        sys.exit(0)
```

Anyway it does not seem a good practice at all. Why do you not try the script A listens the Process Stack and if it finds script B running then stops. This is another example how you could do it.

```
import subprocess
import sys
import psutil

while(1)
    #This sections queries the current processes running
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name'])
        if pinfo[ 'name' ] == "script_B.py":
            sys.exit(0)
   
    do some stuff
    do even more stuff
    if true:
        pid = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "python script_B.py"]) # call subprocess
        sys.exit(0)
```